# How to insert the result of a stored procedure when it has a parameter that doesn't let it's output be inserted into a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and trying this out

```
insert into @temptable
    exec [dbo].[sp_name]
    --list
    --of
    --parameters
```

and I get an error

> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure *sp_name*, Line 841 [Batch Start Line 0]
> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

I have declared the temp table to match the output of the stored procedure, too.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Like the error states, you can't insert / exec a stored procedure that does its own insert exec. So maybe you could share what the stored procedure does, and what you do with `@temptable` after its populated, and how hard it would be to replicate the stored procedure logic, and we may be able to suggest workarounds.

Comment: The original SP does some calculations whose logic I can't understand (business logic, wasn't written by me, but I can decipher of I can give it a read).

Comment: I use the @temptable for further calculations down the line, for the SP I am writing

Comment: Also I don't use the SP perfix :). I just used it here for namesake.

Comment: Read Erland's discussion of [share data between procedures](https://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) for ideas. At this point it seems you need to refactor that original procedure (or duplicate the logic - you choose).